# How to handle exceptions thrown by Tasks in xUnit .net's Assert.Throws<T>?

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0, xunit.net

The following asynchronous `xUnit.net` test with a `lambda` marked with the `async` modifier fails by reporting that no exception was thrown:

```
    [Theory, AutoWebData]
    public async Task SearchWithNullQueryThrows(
        SearchService sut,
        CancellationToken dummyToken)
    {
        // Fixture setup
        // Exercise system and verify outcome
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(async () =>
            await sut.SearchAsync(null, dummyToken));
        // Teardown
    }
```

To make sure that an `ArgumentNullException` is actually thrown I explicitly used a `try-catch` block. It worked, however the resulting code is not clean (compared to the first test):

```
[Theory, AutoWebData]
public async Task SearchWithNullQueryThrows(
    SearchService sut,
    CancellationToken dummyToken)
{
    // Fixture setup
    var expected = typeof(ArgumentNullException);
    Type actual = null;
    // Exercise system
    try
    {
        await sut.SearchAsync(null, dummyToken);
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException e)
    {
        actual = e.GetType();
    }
    // Verify outcome
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    // Teardown
}
```

Why the `Assert.Throws<T>` with the `lambda` marked with the `async` modifier fails?

Comment: This is a known issue: http://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9799

Comment: +1 It seems to be fixed in snapshot `03e3be9a6781` which is before the snapshot `16883cb2351f` where release `2.0.0-alpha` has been associated. However it still doesn't work after updating the solution with NuGet Package Manager.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Update**

This has been solved in xUnit 2, with the addition of `Assert.ThrowsAsync`.

---

I am suspecting that `Assert.Throws` is not `async`-aware. I recommend raising this issue with the xUnit team, suggesting a `ThrowsAsync` be added.

An `async` delegate in this case is returning `Task` or `Task<T>`, and the `ArgumentNullException` is not thrown out of the delegate directly; instead, it is placed on the `Task` (`Task.Exception.InnerException`). `Assert.Throws` is expecting the exception to be thrown out of the delegate directly, not placed on a property of the return value.

You can create your own `AssertEx.ThrowsAsync` as such:

```
public static async Task ThrowsAsync<TException>(Func<Task> func)
{
  var expected = typeof(TException);
  Type actual = null;
  try
  {
    await func();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    actual = e.GetType();
  }
  Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
}
```

which can be used as such:

```
[Theory, AutoWebData]
public async Task SearchWithNullQueryThrows(
    SearchService sut,
    CancellationToken dummyToken)
{
    // Fixture setup
    // Exercise system and verify outcome
    await AssertEx.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentNullException>(async () =>
        await sut.SearchAsync(null, dummyToken));
    // Teardown
}
```

I use a similar approach in MSTest.

Comment: I modified your code slightly, as I believe as it stood only 'ArgumentNullException' would ever get as far as the `Assert`. Another thing that might be worth considering is that the original `Assert.Throws` *returns* the exception (so that you can test exception message too, for example).

Answer (score 3):

If you also need to return the exception to verify it then this might be useful:

```
public static async Task<Exception> AssertThrowsAsync<TException>(Func<Task> func)
    {
        var expected = typeof (TException);
        Exception exception = null;
        Type actual = null;
        try
        {
            await func();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            actual = e.GetType();
            exception = e;
        }
        Assert.NotNull(exception);
        Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        return exception;
    }
```