# Searching for nicer implementation for this unit test

Tags: unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net, fluent-assertions

I use xUnit and FluentAssertions to write my unit tests and I am stuck at the following problem. As I have not implemented the `catch` (in `GetCountriesAsync`) of the `WebException` yet, I throw a new `NotImplementedException` in this place.

This code is the only way I made the test actually work as expected. I added the native xUnit implementation either, due to FluentAssertions is just syntactic sugar.

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetCountriesAsyncThrowsExceptionWithoutInternetConnection()
{
    // Arrange
    Helpers.Disconnect(); // simulates network disconnect
    var provider = new CountryProvider();

    try
    {
        // Act
        var countries = await provider.GetCountriesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Assert FluentAssertions
        e.Should().BeOfType<NotImplementedException>();

        // Assert XUnit
        Assert.IsType<NotImplementedException>(e);
    }
}
```

Though I found this implementation a lot nicer, it just doesn't work.

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetCountriesAsyncThrowsExceptionWithoutInternetConnection3()
{
    // Arrange
    Helpers.Disconnect(); // simulates network disconnect
    var provider = new CountryProvider();

    // Act / Assert FluentAssertions
    provider.Invoking(async p => await p.GetCountriesAsync())
            .ShouldThrow<NotImplementedException>();

    // Act / Assert XUnit
    Assert.Throws<NotImplementedException>(async () => await provider.GetCountriesAsync());
}
```

As VS2012/ReSharper already suggests to remove the redundant `async` keyword of the test method, I replaced `async Task` with `void` and the test still behaves *the same*, so I suspect the async `Action`s cannot be awaited, they're rather fired and forgotten.

Is there a way to implement this properly with xUnit/FluentAssertions? I think I have to go with my first implementation as I can't see any functionality like `InvokingAsync()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle exceptions thrown by Tasks in xUnit .net's Assert.Throws<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084923/how-to-handle-exceptions-thrown-by-tasks-in-xunit-nets-assert-throwst)

Comment: Very nice, exactly what I was searching for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, FA 2.0 has specific support for handling asynchronous exceptions. Just look at the unit tests in [AsyncFunctionExceptionAssertionSpecs](https://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c1bc29ff258e622fac71730955bd1ea066880874#Main/FluentAssertions.Net45.Specs/AsyncFunctionExceptionAssertionSpecs.cs). for various examples.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding FluentAssertions, I've added the following to my code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FluentAssertions
{
    public static class FluentInvocationAssertionExtensions
    {
        public static Func<Task> Awaiting<T>(this T subject, Func<T, Task> action)
        {
            return () => action(subject);
        }
    }
}
```

and now you can do:

```
_testee.Awaiting(async x => await x.Wait<Foo>(TimeSpan.Zero))
        .ShouldThrow<BarException>();
```

whereas `_teste.Wait<T>` returns a `Task<T>`.
Also the naming of the method `Awaiting` make sense, because pure invocation of the method will not result in the exception being caught by the caller, you do need to use await to do so.